# Use reqrep to change the path and then choose a backend based on that path

Tags: haproxy

I have a need to transform the following url (not on the client/browser, but rather between the `frontend` and `backend`):

from:

`http://myhost.com/opt-in/<some_long_guid>.html`

to:

`http://myhost.com/api/distributions/<some_long_guid>/opt-in`

And then at this point choose an appropriate backend.  My `haproxy.conf` file looks like so:

```
frontend www-ssl
   #re-write the url from /opt-in/<dist_id>.html to /api/distributions/<dist_id>/opt-in

   acl url_opt-in path_beg /opt-in
   reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /opt-in/(.*)\.html     \1\ /api/distributions/\2/opt-in if url_opt-in

   acl url_api path_beg /api/

   #choose the api backend if the path starts with /api
   use_backend api-backend if prod url_api

backend api-backend
   server app-1 10.132.93.224:8080 check
   #get rid of the /api part when forwarding to the backend
   reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /api/(.*)     \1\ /\2
```

I have confirmed that hitting `http://myhost.com/api/distributions/<some_long_guid>/opt-in` directly works.

However hitting `http://myhost.com/opt-in/<some_long_guid>.html` gives a `505 - The server does not support the HTTP protocol version used in the request.`

Can anyone see why I might be facing this problem?

**EDIT:** I confirmed that my backend is receiving the request and it is reporting back this 505. I'm trying to see if I can dump the raw-request to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

My `reqrep` statement was chopping off the `HTTP/1.1` after the path. So what was sent to my backend was:

`GET /distributions/038c0abb-8873-457d-889c-0b7c32b5f5c0/opt-in`

instead of:

`/distributions/038c0abb-8873-457d-889c-0b7c32b5f5c0/opt-in HTTP/1.1`

I changed the `reqrep` statement to be:

`reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /opt-in/(.*)\.html(.*)    \1\ /distributions/\2/opt-in\3`

Note the: `\3` at the end, which will add on the `HTTP/1.1`